# rvm problems after changing user name with usermod

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm

I changed my user name, home directory, and group name with the following commands:

```
usermod -l newname oldname
usermod -d /home/newname -m newname
groupmod -n newname oldname
```

There was a bit of fallout from making this change, but the (seemingly) final problem is with Ruby, which I installed through `rvm`. Specifically, none of my Ruby code will run now because various needed resources cannot be located. Example error message:

```
/home/newname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby: error while loading shared libraries: libruby.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Grepping inside `/home/newname/.rvm` for `oldname`, there are many, many (10,000+) results.

Is there a safe way (some `rvm` command, perhaps) to update all the file paths that are listed inside the various files (e.g., `.installed.list` has quite a few occurrences of `oldname`) within my `.rvm` directory to reflect `newname` instead of `oldname`? Or do I just need to uninstall/reinstall everything?

I'm afraid to try fixing this with `sed` because `grep` returned results like

```
Binary file src/ruby-2.4.1/regerror.o matches
```

but I can't see `oldname` anywhere inside this binary file. So, I think `sed` might just put me in a worse position than I am currently in.

I am using Linux Mint 18.3, rvm 1.29.3, and Ruby 2.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest reinstalling `rvm`.

You can wipe out your `rvm` data with `rvm implode`.  Or you could just rename your `~/.rvm` directory to another name so `rvm` can't see it, then install `rvm` and your rubies.

In any given `rvm` ruby installation, you might be able to get away with doing a recursive copy of your $GEM_HOME directory to the new location so you don't have to reinstall your gems (or remember which ones to install).

Comment: Thanks. I was figuring that was what was going to be needed in the end. Especially considering the dearth of responses. As an aside, I see you live part-time in Chiang Mai. Got to visit there last year. Other than the rats, it was a great town!